# MySQL : Getting Entries from a many-to-many table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a following table, I would like to select records which should have all the mentioned values. For example
select `CompanyID` which should have all the three `ProviderID` 200,300,400. So running the query should retrun `CompanyID` 2. Something the opposite of `IN`. Thanks in advance !

```
CompanyID      |        ProviderID
--------------------------------------
    1                 100
    2                 200
    3                 500
    4                 600
    2                 300
    2                 400
    7                 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a `GROUP BY`, select only rows with any of the 3 wanted EmployeeID values. Use `HAVING` to make sure to get 3 different EmployeeID values.

```
select CompanyID
from tablename
where EmployeeID IN (200, 300, 400)
group by CompanyID
having count(distinct EmployeeID) = 3
```

Another approach is a double self join, one for each EmployeeID. However, this is less flexible:

```
select distinct t1.CompanyID
from (select CompanyID from tablename where EmployeeID = 200) t1
join (select CompanyID from tablename where EmployeeID = 300) t2
    on t1.CompanyID = t2.CompanyID 
join (select CompanyID from tablename where EmployeeID = 400) t3
    on t2.CompanyID = t3.CompanyID
```

Comment: IN will check if it matches to any of these values. I want to select rows with entries corresponding to all those values. If it doesnt have even one non matching value it shuldn't return the record

Comment: See the HAVING clause. It's there to make sure you get 3 different EmployeeID values!